# Xcode 6.4 back button disappears

Tags: ios, swift

I'm on Mac OSX El Capitan 10.11.1, Xcode 6.4, iOS SDK 8.4.

I've read through several back button disappearing posts on here and none relate to my issue.

I am creating a shopping app for a Uni assignment. I have created a menu, products list, product detail, cart and checkout storyboard. 
I can successfully navigate from menu -> any other and the back button is there. I can navigate menu -> cart -> checkout without issue also. But when I navigate menu -> product list -> product detail -> cart -> checkout the checkout view loses the back button. I did println(self.navigationController!.navigationBarHidden) and it said false.

I am not hiding any title or navbar or anything.
It's just that this particular way it loses the back button and I tap the area it doesn't detect and suddenly come up.

I have also noticed that the default transition is slide into view from right to left, however when I do the problematic navigation I get a bottom to top slide transition.

Any ideas are appreciated.

:edit:

The code I have tried to execute the segue to the Cart is

```
performSegueWithIdentifier("Cart", sender: nil)
```

I have also tried sender: self. After this the Cart's Checkout segue then has the issue.

Comment: are you using storyboard segues or are you presenting new viewcontrollers from code?

Comment: Any particular reason you are using an outdated Xcode?

Comment: They taught us swift 1.2 with Xcode 6.4 as Xcode 7 wasn't out when we started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that I had linked the segue to the view controller directly and not to the navigation controller. Reconnected the segue to the navigation controller and all is right in the world again.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me like you're presenting the `UIViewController` modally for the checkout screen. If you push the `UIViewController` to navigation stack using `pushViewController(_:animated:)` the navigation controller is gonna create the back button for you.

If you present the controller using `presentViewController(_:animated:completion:)` it's gonna be presented on top of navigation controller (slide from bottom up animation) and the back button is not provided. You need to create your own mechanism to go back. Simplest one being `dismissViewControllerAnimated(_:completion:)`

Easiest way to solve your problem is to change the presenting style. Replace `presentViewController(_:animated:completion:)` with `pushViewController(_:animated:)` which provides the back button so you can finish your uni assignment.

Comment: I'm using the performSegue. I use the same method navigating from menu-> cart -> checkout as the longer route. Just on the longer route it stuffs up.

Comment: Then go through your segues in storyboard and check if any has the kind in Attributes inspector set to `Present modally`. Or try to call `dismissViewControllerAnimater` in the `UIViewController` that doesn't have the back button for easy check to see if you have it presented modally.

Comment: I will check it but that doesn't sound like it will be the case because I move through the segues the same way in both navigation paths just with the number of segue traversals being longer when the issue presents itself. The navigation paths being menu->cart->checkout and menu->product list->product detail->cart->checkout

Comment: this self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true,completion: nil) dismisses the controller and returns to Cart.

Comment: yea, so it's presented modally somehow. Do you have the project somewhere out in the open? This is getting kinda complex to guess what might be wrong

Comment: I just figured it out! I had linked the segues from Product Detail and one I made from Product List directly to the Cart view and not to the cart navigation controller!

Noob mistake...

Comment: Thanks for helping me out.